# How can I calculate the emf-induced with a non-planar surface?

Tags: calculus, integration, derivatives, physics, surface-integrals

Just this question is only for me because I have given any clarifications on the Faraday-Neumann-Lenz for my students of an high school.

We know that the magnetic flux, where $\:S$ is a regolar surface, (with all the hypotesis of regularity, $B\in\mathcal C^1$, etc.), is given by the formula:

$$\Phi_S(\mathbf{B})=\int_S \mathbf{B}\cdot d\mathbf{S} \tag 1$$

Now, the *emf inducted* if given by the formula:

$$\mathcal E_{\text{ind}}=-\frac{d\Phi_S(\mathbf{B})}{dt}=-\frac{d\displaystyle\int_S \mathbf{B}\cdot d\mathbf{S} }{dt} \tag 2$$

If $S$ is a **planar surface** and $\mathbf{B}$ must be an uniform field magnetic, the $(1)$ become:

$$\mathcal E_{\text{ind}}=-\frac{d(BS\cos \alpha)}{dt}$$ 
where the $\alpha$ is the angle between $\mathbf{B}$ and $\mathbf{S}$ and $\mathcal E_{\text{ind}}=\mathcal E_{\text{ind}}(t)$. If $B$ is a function that not depends from the time $t$, therefore (of course),

$$\mathcal E_{\text{ind}}=0$$

If $B=B(t)$ we have:

$$\mathcal E_{\text{ind}}=-S\cos \alpha\: \frac{d B(t)}{dt} \tag 3$$ 
and I can find easily the induced electromotive force and the induced current.

How could I find mathematically the induced electromotive force (emf) and the induced current starting from the formula $(2)$?

> $$\mathcal E_{\text{ind}}=-\frac{d\Phi_S(\mathbf{B})}{dt}=-\frac{d\displaystyle\int_S \mathbf{B}\cdot d\mathbf{S} }{dt} \tag 2$$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The standard thing to do here is to take the derivative "under the integral sign" and get
$$\mathcal E_{\text{ind}} = - \int_S \frac{\partial\mathbf B}{\partial t}\cdot d\mathbf S.$$
At this juncture you might use Faraday's law (Maxwell's equations) to convert this to a flux integral of $\text{curl}\,\mathbf E$.

Comment: I'm sorry for the late reply, thank you very much. I couldn't find anything on the Griffiths text. Introduction to Electrodynamics - David J. Griffiths. Thank you Thank you Thank you Thank you Thank you Thank you (You will find a surprice by me). I imagined that there were partial derivatives.

Comment: I don’t know Griffiths, as I’m a mathematician and not a physicist. Nevertheless, that astonishes me, as it’s basic. It is certainly in Purcell’s E&M text, which I studied my first year of university.